# Within a script in the UI Automation instrument, how do I import another script?

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Within a script written in JavaScript for the UI Automation instrument, how do I import another JavaScript file?

Comment: Be more specific of what you want to do.

Answer (score 7):

Within UI Automation, you can add something like

```
#import "MySharedFunctions.js"
```

at the top of your script to have it pull in code from another JavaScript file.  This can be used for storing common testing or other helper functions within a shared source file.

Comment: Does the file have to be in the same directory? I'm trying to do this, but it keeps telling me "The #import file 'UIAutomationTest-CreateAccount.js' was not found, as required from the script '(null

Comment: @ZS - Possibly. All of the times I've used this, the JavaScript files were in the same directory. I haven't experimented too much with file location.

Comment: You will see the not found error if you have created a new script and have not yet saved it (i.e. exported - menu click on text area). Once you save it the error should go away.

Comment: @ZS you can use `../` to move back up the file tree.